# Change Appended each text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm not getting result properly using append event instead of using ng-repeat in adding each name. Can you please help me how can I change added each name from a single input field. Tell me without using ng-repeat in this, because ng-repeat functionality is not working to me for my further running functionalities, you can solve this using jquery or javascript if it's possible without using ng-repeat. Thanks in advance..
[Here is JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wexinapole/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
       $scope.add_Name = function (index) {
        var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName($index)">{{my.name}} //click<br/></label>';
        var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    };
   
    $scope.selectName = function (index) {
        $scope.showName = true;
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use different name for ng-model to textbox as well as label. **my.name** is used as ng-model for textbox. And in all label you metioned the **{{my.name}}**. Because of this its updating value to all label.

Comment: @user3141852 then how to give expressions to textbox, if i give different name it is not binding to label...

Comment: @user3141852 how the textbox will catch exact label value ... how to give array to appended value ? how to change expression names in textbox??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ng-repeat` would be perfect for such cases. Not sure what makes you avoid that.

You can have a `counter` which will increment every time `Name` is added. Also pass same `counter name` as an argument for `selectName` function.

Every time `selectName` is called, argument value will be set as an `model`

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.my = {
    name: 'untitled'
  };
  var counter = 0;
  $scope.add_Name = function(index) {
    var myName = 'untitled' + counter;
    var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName(\'' + myName + '\')">' + myName + ' //click<br/></label>';
    var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    ++counter;
  };

  $scope.selectName = function(val) {

    $scope.my.name = val;
    $scope.showName = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
  <div id="add"></div>
  <br/>

  <form ng-show="showName">
    <label>Name Change(?)</label>
    <br/>
    <input ng-model="my.name">
  </form>
</body>
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiAJNluHC30BznMemhWn?p=preview)

Comment: thats ok @RayonDabre ..  but if i saved added names in form , if opened that saved form the added data not showing.. if we add again it was adding multiple times.. how can i resolve this issue.. pls tell me.. i'm waiting for ur reply

Comment: thank you so much @RayonDabre .. itz perfectly working.. thnax alot for ur effort ...

Comment: Hi @RayonDabre but it was binding.. it was not changing to the label from textbox

Comment: To bind, you will need object for each created element. That is why `ng-repeat` has to be used.

Comment: ufff....!!! but ng-repeat giving issues to my further functionalities.. isn't it possible from ur code to bind between textbox to label..?? can u pls try again for me .. if u don't mind ..

Comment: thanx for your effort :)